# Restrict OpenVPN access to just some websites

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I want to provide a VPN service with OpenVPN to an acquaintance through my server only to access (a) specific website(s). In fact, even though I trust them to the point of granting them access to my server, I don't want them to be able to do anything and everything on the internet from it since I am the server's owner and held accountable for whatever is done from it.

Is there any way with OpenVPN or from the server's firewall configuration to implement this restriction?

Comment: The answer of @mrc02_kr could work, besides the downside of multiple IPs per website. You should add a proxy solution (or something similar), like squid or privoxy or or or

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow forwarding only to IP addresses, to which your users should have access and then deny forwarding to all. For example:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s $VPN_SUBNET -d $ACESSIBLE_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Iptables rules are processed line by line so if packet is accepted by first rule it won't be dropped by the second one. Of course you have to fit these rules into your existing iptables configuration.

**Edit:**
As @Lenniey pointed out, this solution won't work if you want to allow traffic to websites with CDN or loadbalanced server. Is such case you have to set up proxy server. You can also check what your users do with:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOGGING
```

Comment: This is not a good way to implement this. While I approve of the whitelisting solution, many websites use a CDN or multiple servers/IPs for loadbalancing, so you'd have to add _every_ IP for _every_ website you want to access.